# AWS Elastic Beanstalk load balancer not showing SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

I'm running an Express.js application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and I recently created a SSL/TLS certificate to implement HTTPS for the web application. When I'm in the process of creating an 'Application Load Balancer Listener', as specified in this set of instructions:

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GO9Nm.png)

the SSL/TLS certificate is not showing up.

[image]

I created a certificate using AWS Certificate Manager and have confirmed both were created in the same region: **US East (Ohio) us-east-2**

[image]

Why isn't the certificate showing up when I go to add the listener to the load balancer in my Elastic Beanstalk app?

Comment: Did you try adding it directly to ALB after the EB env has been created?

Comment: @Marcin What do you mean by "adding it directly"? I can't create the ALB because the certificate isn't showing up. Do you mean using the AWS command line interface to create the ALB instead of the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. AWS won't allow you to integrate Amazon Certificate Manager(ACM) created certificates that have **"4096-bit RSA keys or EC keys"** with a load balancer on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ssl-server-cert.html

[image]

In other words, if you're creating a SSL/TLS certificate with ACM and given the choice of what encryption algorithm to use, only the **RSA 2048** option will allow you to use the certificate with an AWS Elastic Beanstalk load balancer.

[image]